# combining output from different scripts into different files in a loop

Tags: awk, files, output, r

This is a follow up to [Replace one entire column in one file with a single value from another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/unix-replace-one-entire-column-in-one-file-with-a-single-value-from-another-fil#238982) combined with [R Pass Variable from R to Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371196/r-pass-variable-from-r-to-unix)

I am running several scripts (Perl, python and R) in one Unix script and need to pass outputs of these scripts to Unix and combine information from different files these scripts create.

I have a working code which is a combination of the above mentioned questions:

The output from the R script called `getenergie.R` is a filename. There are several such filenames which are returned and I need to write into each of these files and replace column 11 of these files with a value which comes from another file (`COP1A_report1`) and is called value.

```
RES=($(./../getenergies.R))
for pdbnames in "${RES[@]}"
do

#write the one value from COP1A_report1 into column 11 of a file and save as TESTING

value=$(awk -F, 'NR==1{print $2;exit}' ./../COP1A_report1) 
awk '{$11 = v} 1' v="$value" ${pdbnames} > TESTING

printf "$value ${pdbnames}\n"
done
```

What I need is a way to loop over this so that it writes one value from `COP1A_report1` (row $2, line 1)  into column 11 of a file called like the first filename stored in `$pdbnames`, save it as a unique file and go to `COP1A_report1` (row $2, line 2), write that into column 11 of a file called like the second filename stored in `$pdbnames` and so on...

What is the smartest way of doing that? I can imagine *something* like the code below, but something is wrong with the syntax and I do not get any errors, just an empty value variable.

Any ideas?

```
counter=1
RES=($(./../getenergies.R))
for pdbnames in "${RES[@]}"
do

value=$(awk -F, 'NR==$counter{print $2;exit}' ./../COP1A_report1) #NR=1 needs to be changed to go through the entire list...
awk '{$11 = v} 1' v="$value" ${pdbnames} > TESTING$counter
counter=$(echo $counter+1 |bc)
printf "$value ${pdbnames}\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass `$counter` into the awk script, so you need to use double-quotes rather than single-quotes.  Single-quotes are for literal strings, double-quotes are for strings with variables in them.

Because you're using double-quotes here, that means you have to escape `$2` as `\$2` in the awk script so that the shell doesn't substitute it's second arg (if any, empty string otherwise) into the awk script.

```
value=$(awk -F, "NR==$counter{print \$2;exit}" ./../COP1A_report1
```

You should also quote other variables when you use them.  e.g. `awk ... > "TESTING$counter"` - lack of quotes was harmless in this instance, but always quoting your variables is a good habit to get into.

Same for `counter=$(echo "$counter"+1 |bc)` - not quoting is harmless here, but still bad practice.

Finally, you're missing the `-v` from the `awk` command when you set `v="$value"`.  should be `-v v="$value"`

```bash
counter=1
RES=($(./../getenergies.R))
for pdbnames in "${RES[@]}"
do

    value=$(awk -F, "NR==$counter{print \$2;exit}" ./../COP1A_report1)
    awk -v v="$value" '{$11 = v} 1' "$pdbnames" > "TESTING$counter"
    counter=$(echo "$counter"+1 |bc)
    printf "$value $pdbnames\n"

done
```

Comment: Ok. this works. I realise this is a bit off topic, but can you recommend a good blog/book etc on more good practices in unix programming? I would like to avoid the "don't s" in the future, wherever possible...

Comment: can't recommend a book, but there's lots of good examples here.  Look especially for answers by 
Stéphane Chazelas and Gilles....they really know their stuff and generally provide exceptionally well written and detailed answers.   http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles