# Replace a column and preserve spacing

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

This is a follow up to [unix: replace one entire column in one file with a single value from another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/unix-replace-one-entire-column-in-one-file-with-a-single-value-from-another-fil#238982)

I am trying to replace one column of a file (file1) with one specific value from another file (file2).

file1 is structured like this:

```
HETATM    8  P   FAD B 600      98.424  46.244  76.016  1.00 18.65
HETATM    9  O1P FAD B 600      98.634  44.801  75.700  1.00 17.69 O  
HETATM   10  O2P FAD B 600      98.010  46.640  77.387  1.00 15.59 O  
HETATM   11 H5B1 FAD B 600      96.970  48.950  72.795  1.00 -1.00 H
```

and I absolutely need to conserve that structure.

file2 is structured like this:

```
1 27, -81.883, 4.0
5 48, -67.737, 20.0
1 55, -72.923, 4.0
4 27, -62.64, 16.0
```

I noticed that awk is "misbehaving" and looses the format of my pdb file, meaning that instead of:

```
HETATM    1  PA  FAD B 600      95.987  47.188  74.293  1.00 -73.248
```

I get

```
HETATM 1 PA FAD B 600 95.887 47.194 74.387 1.00 -73.248
```

I have tried:

```
file1="./Min1_1.traj_COP1A_.27.pdb"
file2="./COP1A_report1"
value="$(awk -F, 'NR==1{print $2;exit}' $file2)"
#option 1: replaces the column I want but messes up the format
awk -F ' ' '{$11 = v} 1' v="$value" $file1 >TEST1
#option 2: keeps the format but adds the value at the end only
awk -F ' ', '{$2 = v} 1' v="$value" $file1 >TEST2
awk -F, '{$11 = v} 1' v="$value" $file1 >TEST3
```

I guess it is because a pdb file does not have the same delimiters for all columns and awk is not dealing with that in the manner I want it to.

Any ideas how to "tame" awk for this problem or what other command to use?

Comment: Dirty hack: Add a `tr ' ' '\t' TEST1` pass. Tabs align things!

Comment: If the separator is a tabulation you may set `awk` to use a tabulation as the output field separator: `awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}; {$11 = v} 1' v="$value" $file1 >TEST1`. Otherwise use one of the methods in the answers below, they are all valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex (`[^[:blank:]]` i.e. non-blank) and replace the `11`th match:

```
awk '{print gensub (/[^[:blank:]]+/, v, 11)}' v="$value" infile
```

Same with `sed`:

```
sed "s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/${value}/11" infile
```

---

Another way, if your file has fixed length fields and you know the "position" of each field (e.g. assuming only spaces in your sample file, the 11th field takes up 4 chars, from 57th to 60th on each line)

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,56) v substr($0,61)}' v=$value file
```

or

```
sed -E "s/^(.{56}).{4}(.*)$/\1${value}\2/" infile
```

Comment: `gensub()` is a GAWK feature and is not specified by POSIX. It may not be available in other versions of AWK.

Answer (score 2):

With GAWK 4, you can preserve the field separators by explicitly splitting a string (or the whole line) and iterating over the result of the split (fields and separators) for output.

This example uses `FPAT` (a regex specifying the field structure) and `patsplit()` but could use `FS` (a regex specifying the field separator or containing a single space to represent `[ \t\n]+`) and `split()` instead.

```
gawk "v=$value" '{n = patsplit($0, arr, FPAT, seps); arr[11] = v; for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]}; print ""}'
```

Note that `a[0]` will always be null, `seps[0]` will contain any leading separator and `seps[n]` will be any separator characters (whitespace) at the end of the input line.'

Here is the oneliner in a more readable form:

```
gawk "v=$value" '
    {
        n = patsplit($0, arr, FPAT, seps); 
        arr[11] = v; 
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]
        }; 
        print ""
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd offer to use `sed` for your task:

```
file1="./Min1_1.traj_COP1A_.27.pdb"
file2="./COP1A_report1"
IFS=',' read -r a value b <"$file2"
#for second field:
sed "s/.[0-9]\b/$value/" "$file1" > TEST1
#for 11th field:
sed "s/\S.\.[0-9]\{2\}\b/$value/" "$file1" > TEST1
```